# Issue With Join Doubling Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen several posts about this on Stack Overflow, but none of them seems to give me an answer that I can understand.

I am trying to join several relations together in order to get all of the relevant information to output all routes that start in China and end in the United States.

In the `SeaRoute` relation, the `start_port` and `end_port` are stored as `INT` and in the `Port` relation the `pid` corresponds to the `start_port` and `end_port` and includes a `pcountry` column.

I am starting off with just trying to output everything that has a start_port that is in China.  I am expecting 3 results from my `Record` relation as those are the only ones that start with China in the table; However, I am receiving 6 records at the output (all of the results appear to have been doubled if I go back and audit what's in the table).

While I want the right answer, I am more concerned that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of `Inner Join` and the other `Join` methods.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *
FROM Record
INNER JOIN Goods AS Go_data 
    ON Record.gid = Go_data.gid
LEFT JOIN SeaRoute AS SR 
    ON Record.rid = SR.rid
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT pid, pcountry AS starting_port_country
            FROM Port
            INNER JOIN SeaRoute AS SR ON Port.pid = SR.start_port
            WHERE Port.pcountry = 'China') 
            AS start_port_table ON SR.start_port = start_port_table.pid
```

Comment: provide your sample data and also your expected output in table format

Comment: post table structure

Comment: A popular principle is that there are only 2 joins: 'left' and 'inner' (and I suppose, at a push, 'cross'). Together with 'union', it should be able to construct any required relationship.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` combined with `RIGHT JOIN` is a mess... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`. My advice is to switch table order and do `LEFT JOIN` always (almost.)

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I'm suspicious of why you are joining on a subquery, with an additional `SeaRoute AS SR`, rather than just `Port` directly (`RIGHT JOIN Port ON Port.pid = SR.start_port AND Port.pcountry = 'China'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your query, you want to be INNER JOINing between the records that you have only on the routes that you want.

You know all of the SeaRoutes that start in China and end in the United States already, you do however need to join to the Ports table twice like so:

```
SELECT  sr.rid,
        sp.pcountry AS starting_port_country,
        ep.pcountry AS end_port_country
FROM dbo.SeaRoute sr
    INNER JOIN dbo.Port sp ON sp.pid = sr.start_port
    INNER JOIN dbo.Port ep ON ep.pid = sr.end_port
WHERE   sp.pcountry = 'China'
    AND ep.pcountry = 'United States'
```

Then you just need to join that to your main query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Record
    INNER JOIN dbo.Goods AS Go_data     ON Record.gid = Go_data.gid
    INNER JOIN  
        (
            SELECT  sr.rid,
                    sp.pcountry AS starting_port_country,
                    ep.pcountry AS end_port_country
            FROM dbo.SeaRoute sr
                INNER JOIN dbo.Port sp ON sp.pid = sr.start_port
                INNER JOIN dbo.Port ep ON ep.pid = sr.end_port
            WHERE   sp.pcountry = 'China'
                AND ep.pcountry = 'United States'
        ) ports ON ports.rid = Record.rid
```

There's no way I can explain joins to you any clearer than this page can:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins